# What privileges are required to store an SSIS package in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

I want to create an SSIS package as a DB User.

Also I want to store it to SQL Server, not in file system. The DB User only has the **db_owner** privilege on a particular database.

What least privileges are required to save SSIS to SQL Server?

Already I have assigned the following:

```
grant execute on dbo.sp_ssis_checkexists to test
grant execute on dbo.sp_ssis_putpackage to test
```

Please provide feedback, thanks.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this question? I've asked a similar question (1105241), as I've tried adding them to every group I can find, and they still can't connect to SSIS.

Comment: any final solution about it ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/security/integration-services-roles-ssis-service?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 6):

Please add the user to following roles in `msdb` database:

- db_dtsadmin
- db_dtsltduser
- db_dtsoperator

Hope it works.

More information on the Integration Services Roles in SQL Server 2005 can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141053%28v=sql.90%29.aspx.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone gets to this question misled by the title (it says Sql Server 2008 while the tags mention sql-server-2005), the privileges for the `msdb` database in SQL Server 2008 are:

```
db_ssisadmin
db_ssisltduser
db_ssisoperator
```

Comment: I've edited the title to reflect the tag, but still: valid point. Addition: see [Using Integration Services Roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141053%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for more information on the roles in SQL Server 2008 (R2).